# SAP Hana Repository Activation Error: Unjoined Table found

Tags: runtime-error, hana

So like the title says. I've built all my tables, no errors. Built all my attribute views, no errors. I go to activate my analytical views and I get un-joined table errors for both of my analytical views. I'm not sure where this is coming from since each table has it's key.

I am including the key from each table in the data foundation, could this be the issue? although I have tried adding the table it says is un-joined to the star join and still get the un-joined error.

I have tried looking online for SAP Hana Unjoined errors or activation errors in general but nothing seems to touch on this particular issue. Let me know if there is any additional detail I could provide as I'm pretty novice with SAP Hana. Thank you.

[image: prescriber analytical view]

[image: income analytical view]

Comment: Generally speaking, attribute and analytical views shouldn't be used anymore. They've been deprecated for many years now. Instead, use calculation views for your data models.

Comment: This unfortunately is for a class project I'm working on with a teammate and this is the method we are expected to use.

Comment: In this case, you may want to post the actual view design so that we can have a look at it.

Comment: Also: That class project seems rather outdated...

Comment: ok ive added the views